# Merge Intellij IDEs to have only one installed

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, phpstorm, rubymine, appcode

This is a basic question.
I use Android Studio, AppCode, IntelliJ IDEA, PHPStorm and RubyMine.

Is there any way to merge all of those IDEs?
For example, IntelliJ IDEA with plugins for each type of development instead of having 5 IDEs that are basically the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Intellij IDEA Ultimate includes all the features available in PHPStorm and RubyMine (but you need installing some missing plugins from the repository). Same for Android Studio (https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/). So you can just use Intellij IDEA for Ruby, PHP and Android development. AppCode, however, can't be replaced with IDEA